# How do I refactor multiple similar methods of this sort into a single method?

Tags: c#, refactoring, properties

Suppose I have a number of related classes that all have a method like this:

```
protected override OnExecute()
{
    this.constructorParm.BoolProperty = !this.constructorParm.BoolProperty;
}
```

The type of `constructorParm` may change (it may also be a `static` `Setting`), and the specific property will certainly change, but the type of the property will always be `bool`.

Suppose further that I've decided it's silly to have 8 different classes that all do the exact same thing on an implementation level- toggle a bool value.  Especially when they're all related on a semantic level also (they all derive from the same `Command` abstract base class, which is where `OnExecute()` comes from).

How to I parameterize the property that I want to toggle without parameterizing the actual toggle operation itself?  For example, I know I can do something like this (uncompiled):

```
internal class CommandX
{
    Action doExecute = null;
    public CommandX(Action executeAction) { this.doExecute = executeAction; }
    protected override OnExecute() { this.doExecute(); }
}

// elsewhere
var b = new CommandX(() => {target.BoolProperty = !target.BoolProperty;});
```

but how I can I capture the toggling behavior in the class, while still accepting the writable property as a parameter?  (If I pass the toggling in as a parameter, then I'm just making an over-complicated delegate.)

(I can't just pass the property in b/c `bool` is a value type, so I'd just be toggling a copy.  I can't pass it in by ref, of course, b/c properties can't be passed by ref.  I feel like there's got to be something stupid and obvious that I'm just really missing here.  :) )

### **Context**

The reason I'm doing such a simple thing in an indirect manner is actually due to the use of the GoF Command pattern in winforms.  The core functionality `Command`s are more complex, but this small subset of `Command`s essentially just toggles a property that will raise PropertyChanged events elsewhere.  Instead of having all these commands in separate classes, I wanted to fold them into one because they're so simple.

Comment: You can't refactor this kind of stuff well. You'd need good metaprogramming facilities (i.e. macros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Reflection to select which property to toggle by using the [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) class:

```
string propertyName = "BoolProperty";
Foo myFoo = new Foo();
Type myFooType = myFoo.GetType();
PropertyInfo prop = myFooType.GetProperty(propertyName);
prop.SetValue(myFoo, !((bool)prop.GetValue(myFoo, null)), null);
```

You'd only have to keep the name of the property that you'd like to toggle.

However, this would only make sense if "toggling a property" makes explicit part of your design. Otherwise, it would definately be overkill for something this basic when the "easy" solution is to just toggle the property normally.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make use of reflection to specify what property to change, but if there are a limited number of options (you mention there are 8 classes), I would recommend that you use a switch statement, and have an enumeration in the class constructor.

```
internal enum PropertyOption { Prop1, Prop2 }

internal class Bar {
  PropertyOptiion prop;
  public Bar(PropertyOption prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
  }
  public override OnFoo() {
    switch (prop) {
      case PropertyOption.Prop1:
        this.prop1 = !this.prop1;
        break;
      case PropertyOption.Prop2:
        this.prop2 = !this.prop2;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers here

I'm afraid I'm not an expert on any of these. But I think the situations are similar.

[Can you refactor out a common functionality from these two methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735473/can-you-refactor-out-a-common-functionality-from-these-two-methods)